# How to use generic typescript methods in a non-typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm working on a project built with React, based on [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). I will be using a library that was written in typescript. How can I use generic methods, defined in this library, in my project? Currently, I'm getting an error in Visual Studio Code, saying "'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file.". What's the best way to solve this?

I'm new to working with react and typescript, so pardon me if this is a dumb question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're try to use TS in JS project the best way to start is add `// @ts-check` comment on top of each file. VSC will "check" you file with TypeScript compiler, e.g.

```
// @ts-check
[] + {} // ERROR
```

Of course `[] + {}` is still syntax valid JS code but TS complier will throw error here.

Lib written in TS should be type by `// @ts-check` automatically.

Second stem is compile hole JS project by TypeScript compiler:

```
npm i typescript --save-dev
npx tsc src/main.js --allowJs --out /dev/null
```

`--allowJs` allow compiler to works on `.js` files. Output is `/dev/null` because we don't want to have any compiled files, we just want to know that compiler throws error or not.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. create-react-app with typescript

You can create react project with typescript enabled

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

And add allowJs in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowJs": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

This way you can have mixed type files `*.js` and `*.ts` to use typescript on demand.

#### 2. Enable typing in JS

by adding `// @ts-check` on top of file you enable typescript linting on `*.js` files